# FirebaseError not being caught by try/catch block in signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a react app using Firebase for authentication, and I'm trying to use the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method to log in a user. The login process works correctly when the email and password are correct, but when the password is wrong, the application crashes with the following error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/wrong-password).

I've wrapped the call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword` in a try/catch block, but it doesn't seem to be catching the error. Right below is the function:

```
 const login = async ({email, password}) => {
    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
        // handle the wrong password error here
        console.log(error.code);
      } else {
        // handle other errors here
        console.log("There was an error");
      }
    }
  }
```

I've also tried wrapping the call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword` in a `Promise.catch` block, like this:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
      // handle the wrong password error here
      console.log(error.code);
    } else {
      // handle other errors here
      console.log("There was an error");
    }
  });
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. The error message still appears in the console and the application crashes. What am I doing wrong? How can I catch the FirebaseError thrown by signInWithEmailAndPassword in my code? Here is the call stack summary:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/wrong-password).
    at auth.js:88
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.np (auth.js:87)
    at iw.signInWithEmailAndPassword (auth.js:209)
    at login (App.js:20)
    at HTMLFormElement.handleSubmit (App.js:33)
```

[Here's the full code](https://pastebin.com/fGScdLuk) for the page route if more context is still needed.

Comment: Everything relevant to understanding the question is in the code. The rest are supplementary like you said.

Comment: `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is imported from Firebase, I didn't make the function

Comment: Wait, so your Pastebin links were the Firebase code? That made things very confusing. Where do you see this error / in what context? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Please don't include the Firebase source code in your question. It is unnecessary

Comment: The pastebin was the stack trace. Was about including it in the question . Off topic, I know I'm not the best at asking questions but I'm trying.

Comment: What you posted in pastebin was source code. A stack trace is part of an error report. Perhaps a screenshot of the error would help

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZNrv2dQ

Comment: You seem to have your debugger set to pause on any exception. This all appears to be working as expected. If you don't want to be alerted, uncheck the _"Pause on exceptions"_ checkbox then you'll only see uncaught errors

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a stupid idiot. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, my debugger was enabled to "Pause on exceptions" which was causing it to throw the error. All I had to do was turn that off.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).